# Project Euler #18: Maximum Path Sum I

Tags: java

So basically I interpreted this problem as follows:

```
   3
  7 4
 2 4 6
8 5 9 3
```

The two number below the starting should be compared and the larger should be picked as the new number. So in this case, it would be 3, then 7, then 4, then 9. Sum them up, get the answer of 23. I wrote a program to achieve this:

```
public class ProblemEighteen {

private static int pos = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Problem18Text"));
        int sum = 0;
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            final String line = in.nextLine();
            int big = getBiggestNum(line);
            sum += big;
            System.out.println(big);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static int getBiggestNum(String line) {
    final String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
    if (numbers.length == 1) {
        pos = 1;
        return Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
    } else {
        int i = 1;
        int numOne = -1;
        int numTwo = -1;
        for (final String num : numbers) {
            if (pos == i) {
                numOne = Integer.parseInt(num);
            } else if (pos + 1 == i) {
                numTwo = Integer.parseInt(num);
            }
            i++;
            if (numOne != -1 && numTwo != -1)
                break;
        }
        if (numOne > numTwo) {
            return numOne;
        } else {
            pos += 1;
            return numTwo;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine for the example I gave above, but when I put in the actual problem to solve, it said I got it wrong (I got 1064). I added a print statement to see what numbers it was selecting and it got them all right (based on how I understood what I was trying to find) but I still got it wrong... Anyone know why?

Comment: You are *really* close. Not quite sure why it's not working, but to give yourself less of a headache, you might want to read the entire triangle into an array at the beginning (rather than messing with Strings throughout the entire program).

Comment: Baum: Oh wow it makes me feel good that I'm really close! I'll change it from manipulating strings to an array-based operation to clean the code out and then I should be able to diagnose the problem a bit easier. I'll update the OP later when I get back from the airport.

Comment: Another comment (but it won't necessarily fix it): looks like you shouldn't be using an enhanced for (for each) loop. You have a counter, `i`. So just use a regular for loop.

Comment: your interpretation of the problem is wrong. consider this triangle : `1\n1 2\n9 1 2` solution is 11, but your algorithm gives 5. you need to read the triangle from the bottom up and use dynamic programing to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've solved this problem, but you'll find that it's best that you start at the bottom of the triangle and work your way up.  Especially, when you get to problem 67.

If you read your data into an array as baum suggested, you'd have data that looks like this:

```
3  0  0  0
7  4  0  0
2  4  6  0
8  5  9  3
```

So start at the bottom taking two numbers at a time and comparing a sum to their adjacent number in the next above row.

```
8 + 2 = 10 or 5 + 2 = 7.  10 is greater so replace the 2 with the 10.  
5 + 4 = 9 or 9 + 4 = 13.  13 is greater so replace the 4 with the 13.
9 + 6 = 15 or 3 + 6 = 9.  15 is greater so replace the 6 with 15.
```

Now move up one row and perform the same checks until you get to the very top and the very top should contain the correct answer.

Comment: That's pretty much [Floyd's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) isn't it (but in this case you're finding the longest path)

Comment: Not familiar with Floyd's Algorithm.  See https://projecteuler.net/problem=18 for what is trying to be accomplished.

Comment: If you check out the link I posted, you'll see Floyd's algorithm is a shortest-path-finding algorithm for weighted, directed graphs, which is basically what the triangle is.  You can modify the comparisons in the algorithm to make it a longest path instead (which is very similar to what you suggested in your answer)